# Android sip stack with codec manipulation support?

Tags: java, android, sip, codec

I have been looking for some framework for an android device that enables the reInvite method over the SIP protocol. My utter goal is to be able to switch codecs while in call. I have tried to do so with some existing libraries but i have come to a dead-end. 
I have tried to use [SipDroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout) which has a set_codec() method but I haven't managed to find any decent documentation about that. I have also tried with the native android.net.sip library but I didn't seem to find out how to change them there either... Does anyone have any advice on such a library that supports reInvite in the way I have described, or any tips on using the libraries I have mentioned? Thank you in advance...

ps : I have tried using mobicents and asterisk as servers..

Comment: As far as I know SipDroid use JAIN-SIP library. So you may try to go thru JAIN-SIP document which is easily available. After identified with JAIN-SIP you can trace method in SipDroid.

Comment: what is you meaning of 'switch codecs while in call' do you mean you can switch the codec when you are talking with somebody in a call?

Comment: Yes, via the reInvite method.

Comment: Is android.net.sip class have the posibility to change codeck? How to change codeck from g711 to some other??? Does anybody knows? Thanks...

Comment: I is an old question but anyway SioDroid uses MjSip. Not JAIN

Answer (score 2):

If you Google you will find several free SIP stacks for Android, most of them are based on "C++\C" code - examples [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/apps.htm) and [linphone](http://www.linphone.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any free solution, but there is at least one commercial sip framework for android that allow switching codecs.

In theory, you could also

Comment: Thank you Hank Karl, I'm afraid that theory does not always cut the mustard. We seem to be here in a territory that is neither stable nor perfectly documented...

Answer (score 0):

I know that IntegrIT CrystalVu SDK http://www.integrit.com/  supports codecs switching "on the fly" for encoder and decoder. Also it includes special module of blind codec type detection based on incoming  RTP stream analysis.